# What could be wrong to my h4n zoom recorder

Tags: recording

Every time I switch on my h4N, it takes quite a long time to load.  After I finish recording and press the stop button, it also takes a very long time to complete.

When the screen finally appears in stand by mode again and I want to try to listen to my recent recording, it says "invalid file".

What's actually happen here?

I tried taking off the battery when it was still in processing to complete the recording. Since I need to record a new one, but I can't start it without the recording on stand by mode, hence I took out the battery of it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few steps to investigate further :

- check that your h4n firmware is up to date
- check that the SD card you are using for recording is supported (here's [an example for h4n pro](https://www.zoom-na.com/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/H4n_H4nPro_compatible_cards_en_0.pdf)).
- try to reformat the SD card as your attempt to cut power while recording might have leave either a file or the filesystem in a corrupted state.
- as @aj-henderson suggested, check that your card functions in another device.

Comment: I'd also verify if the SD card functions in other devices.  It sounds either too slow or corrupt,